# Не могу понять как работает пример программы из книги,цикл for в цикле for

Tags: java, циклы, for

Задание из 5 главы книги Head Firs:Java

```
class MixFor5{
public static void main(String[]args){
  int x=0;
  int y=30;
  for (int outer=0; outer<3; outer++){
    for (int inner=4; inner>1; inner--){
      x=x+3;
      y=y-2;
      if (x==6){
        break;
      }
      x=x+3;
     }
    y=y-2;
   }
  System.out.println(x+" "+y);
 }
}

ответ: 54 6
```

Объясните,если можно поэтапно,как получится в итоге 54 и 6?Никак не могу понять,как не считаю 54 6 не получается.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Внешний* цикл повторяется 3 раза - для значений 0, 1 и 2 переменной `outer`.

*Внутренний* цикл повторяется для каждой из 3 итераций внешнего цикла *максимально* 3 раза - для значений 4, 3 и 2 переменной `inner`. *Максимально* потому что он может прекратится при условии `x==6`:

```
  if (x==6){
    break;
  }
```

Но и теперь следуйте:

Первый переход внешним циклом, первый переход внутренним циклом:

```
  x=x+3;      //  0 + 3, результат:  3
  y=y-2;      // 30 - 2, результат: 28
  if (x==6){
    break;
  }
  x=x+3;      //  3 + 3, результат:  6
```

Первый переход внешним циклом, второй переход внутренним циклом:

```
  x=x+3;      //  6 + 3, результат:  9
  y=y-2;      // 28 - 2, результат: 26
  if (x==6){
    break;
  }
  x=x+3;      //  9 + 3, результат: 12
```

Первый переход внешним циклом, третий переход внутренним циклом:

```
  x=x+3;      // 12 + 3, результат: 15
  y=y-2;      // 26 - 2, результат: 24
  if (x==6){
    break;
  }
  x=x+3;      // 15 + 3, результат: 18
```

Вы можете видеть, что `x` всегда увеличатся на `6` и `y` уменьшается на `2`; это будет повторятся всего 9 раза (3 раза внутренний цикл во всяком из 3 внешних циклов; условие для `break` не встретится), и так как

```
int x=0;        // первоначальные значение для x:  0
int y=30;       // первоначальные значение для y: 30
```

Значит, конечные значения этих переменных бы могли быть

```
x =  0 + 9*6    // 54
y = 30 - 9*2    // 12
```

Но погодите: в конце внешнего цикла команда

```
y=y-2;
```

и эта команда выполнится 3 раза (3 переходы внешним циклом), также в конце концов переменная `y` еще уменьшится на 6 и ее значение будет не 12, а 6.

И точно эти значения переменных `x` и `y` ваша программа выведет.